# Restart of apache2 fails on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I also tried to add webserver localhost to this file sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and got this output when I tried to restart apache2:

```
ubuntu@webserver:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 38 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'webserver', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included        in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!
```

Below is what was in the sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn file:

```
webserver localhost
```

I then got this output:

```
ubuntu@webserver:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn:
Invalid command 'webserver', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included   in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

...fail!

Below is what was in the apache error log:

```
[Tue Mar 25 12:35:48 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 25 12:41:47 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 25 12:41:48 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 25 12:44:01 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 25 12:53:18 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Mar 25 12:53:19 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 28 18:19:42 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
webserver localhost
```

is invalid. You have to remove it.

Use [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) if you want to set the FQDN:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Comment: I did that and then ran this command with this output: ubuntu@webserver:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                                             ... waiting                                                          Is this expected? I still can't view the "It works!" from the local host in the web browser.

Comment: The config seems to be fixed but Apache is waiting for something when starting. See if there's something about that in the log files.

Comment: This is what's currently in the log:                                            
[Fri Mar 28 19:46:02 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 28 19:48:30 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 28 19:48:31 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations